# Detect beacon hardware failure in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ibeacon

I am trying to connect to the beacon hardware via iOS devices and I am able to achieve this using iBeacon technology.

Now, I would like to know if there is a way available in iOS to identify if any of the beacon hardware is failed.

The methods listed below are just to notifying me whether the iOS device has entered any beacon region or not.

-locationManager:didEnterRegion:

-locationManager:didExitRegion:

I am trying to get the details of hardware device failure so that I can log this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no part of the beacon spec that will broadcast error codes. It gives out an UUID, a major and minor values, with other elements like range coming from the OS and its reading of the power of the transmission.

Some beacons provide other ways of getting information, like temperature on Estimote beacons, but these are on a beacon by beacon basis.

There isn't much to go wrong in a beacon besides the battery and the bluetooth hardware, and if either of these break the device wouldn't be able to transmit an error code anyways.

Comment: Thank you Gary for this quick update. Further to your answer, let us assume that I am looking for a specific combination of UUID, a major and a minor value and such combination is never being tracked in any of the delegate/listener method of location manager. In this case, I can blindly commit that there must be some issue with the battery or the bluetooth hardware. Correct me if what I am understanding from your answer is wrong.

Comment: You can't assume that not seeing the combination of UUID, major and minor means the beacon is broken. Bluetooth could be off on your device, you could be too far away or the beacon could have been removed.

Comment: Yes Gary, agreed with your suggestion. It seems, I was making too many assumptions :) Thanks again for your inputs.

Comment: No worries, if it's correct could you mark it as the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Like Gary said, beacons dont broadcast error codes. I have beacons that not works correctly ( wrong distance ). I suggest you to implement a filter. This Filter need to check rsi value of each beacons. By comparing this rsi value with values of others beacons, maybe you can determine wich beacon is broke and ignore it. Sorry for my poor english. I hope this can help you.
Best regards.

Comment: You can also use estimote app. if u use the beacon detection in list mode, you can check all values of your beacons. Using this tools, i have found that i had some beacons that dont works correctly. Even with a good calibration my devices get wrong distance value for these beacons.